# Can a valid email address contain a newline character?

Tags: validation, email

I'm dealing with some email parsing and validation and I'm wondering if a valid email address can contain a newline character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for e-mail address to contain a newline.
This should help: [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Here's a diagram, note there's no 0x0a character anywhere:
[image]

Comment: According to this https://github.com/jackbearheart/email-addresses/issues/36#issuecomment-366471840 ` \r\n ` is allowed. From many of the answers in your link I'm also seeing `CRLF`. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @Awesome-o the URL I have provided referring numerous RFC documents. Please, use them instead of someone's github page that has absolutely no authority.

Comment: to reiterate, an answer in the exact link you provided mentions `CRLF` which is found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14075810/1979235 . Furthermore, RFC 5322 has 72 matches of the string `CRLF`, but no mention of your diagram. So without an explanation of why these `CRLF`'s exist I can't accept your answer as correct.